# Removing all nodes from linked list (given a start and an end index)

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I'm writing an extra `removeRange()` method that except a `start index` and `end index` as parameters.  I've passed all the conditions except when the number of nodes equals the range from start to end.

example my linked list contains:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
```

after the method `removeRange(0,2)` is called:

list should become `null`, since from 0 to 2, the count is 3 and there are also 3 elements in my list.

look at the picture for a better idea of what's going on if you can.

[image]

**Code:**

```
public void removeRange(int start, int end) {
    if(start < 0 || end < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } 
    if(start == 0 && end == 0) {
        front = front.next;
    } else if (start == 0 && end == 1) {
        front = front.next.next;
    } else {
        ListNode head = front;
        for(int i = 0; i < start-1;i++) {
            head = head.next;
        }
        ListNode tail = front;
        for(int i = 0; i < end;i++) {
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        head.next = tail.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the fields in your linked list class?

Comment: `private ListNode front`;   ...and for `ListNode` class well just `public int data` and `public ListNode next`

Comment: OK so `front` is the the beginning on your linked list. Just FYI the CS terminology tends to use `head` to refer to start of the list and `tail` the pointer to the last node.

Comment: uhm well yeah sorry if the names for my variable is off the track, which make it harder for others to understand. I'll be more careful next time. But it's ok now..since i got the problem solved.  Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `tail.next == null` then you still need to set `front = head` as you have done similarly in your previous cases where you update `front`.

Comment: well thanks for the idea.  i put an extra condition in my last case that `if (start == 0 && tail.next == null)` then `front = null;` which solved my problem.

Comment: @JavaWannabee glad it helped. Depending on how you have defined your `ListNode`, unless you've set it otherwise in the constructor, `next` is already `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to code any linked data structures (lists, trees, graphs) is to get a white board, and draw the linked list.  Then, for the test input, step through the code one line at a time, just like the computer would execute it.  For each line, make the corresponding change on the drawn version.  At some point the code will tell you to draw something that you know isn't right, and that tells you where your problem is.

One thing I noticed in your code, is that you don't make sure the input range are withing the size of the list.  What if the list is 5 nodes long, and someone calls removeRante(10, 12)?

For this particular problem, you have 4 cases, and you should test for and handle them in this order. .
1.  Start = head and End = tail, at which point you make head and tail both null, thus emptying the linked list.
2. Start = head. Move head  to point to  end + 1. 
3. End = tail.  Move tail to start - 1.
4. Everything else. Head = start + 1, tail = end - 1.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing it out.  Since my online grader is not asking for this condition, and i'm being lazy right now so i'll just leave the code like that.  But i'll remember this.